# updating the elements of a list from null to object doesn't cause recompostion

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, compose-recomposition

I have a `mutableList` in my `ViewModel` that has a fixed size and it's intialized by **null** but when I **update** an element from the `List` from **null** to a `LetterGridBtn` I see in my logs that **list has been updated** but the **recompostion is not triggered** and i don't understand why.

> my ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class QuestionScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userPointsRepository: UserPointsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _lettersGridList: MutableStateFlow<List<LetterGridBtn>> =
        MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    val lettersGridList = _lettersGridList.asStateFlow()


    private val _userAnswerInput: MutableStateFlow<MutableList<LetterGridBtn?>> = MutableStateFlow(
        MutableList(_correctAnswer.value.length) { null }
    )
    val userAnswerInput = _userAnswerInput.asStateFlow()

    fun onLetterGridBtnClick(index: Int) {
        if (_userAnswerInput.value.count { it != null } <= _correctAnswer.value.length) {
            val letterBtnClicked = _lettersGridList.value[index]
            letterBtnClicked.isClicked.value = true
            _userAnswerInput.value.addElementToFirstEmptyIndex(letterBtnClicked)
            _userAnswerInput.value.forEach {
                Log.d("btnVisibilty", it.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> LetterGridBtn:

```
data class LetterGridBtn(
    val letter : Char,
    val isClicked : MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false),
    val index : Int
)
```

> my composable:

```
@Composable
fun QuestionScreen(
    viewModel: QuestionScreenViewModel
) {
    val letterGridList by viewModel.lettersGridList.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    val userAnswerInput by viewModel.userAnswerInput.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

//some code
     AnswerField(
      correctAnswer = correctAnswer,
      userAnswerInput = userAnswerInput,
      modifier = Modifier
           .fillMaxWidth(0.95f)
           .fillMaxHeight(0.25f)
     )
}

@Composable
fun AnswerField(
    correctAnswer: String,
    userAnswerInput : List<LetterGridBtn?>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {

            for (i in 0 until answerSize) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                        .padding(end = 2.dp)
                        .aspectRatio(1f)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                        .background(lightOrange),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "${userAnswerInput[i]?.letter}",
                        fontSize = 20.nonSP,
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**I would really appretiate an explanation along with the answer**

Comment: It has no way to detect you changed contents of a mutable list. You should use an immutable list instead, and update the mutable state with a new list.

Comment: so it can't detect changes in mutable list now i understand

Comment: For reference: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability